# Upgrade to latest tomcat/ JRE or stick with what's provided by LTS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server, java

Running a server with Ubuntu 12.04 which ships Tomcat 7.0.26. Should I care about updating the tomcat installation to latest 7.0.42 version or should I stick with what's provided? If I stick then am I not vulnerable to threats & bugs in 7.0.26 version ? I've been suggested to always use the latest minor version for things like JRE 7, Tomcat 7 etc, does it not hold good here ?

Answer (score 1):

Never use mission critical tools as they are distributed with your Linux distro. They often lag several versions behind and may not be configured in the way you expect. For instance Python always installs add-on packages in a directory called site-packages, except on Debian and Ubuntu distros.

There are two ways to approach these mission critical components, i.e. the things that are mission critical for your business and for the purpose that you have for a given server. The first is more or less manual, but it can be automated with a bash script. In this variant you download the package from what distros call "upstream". This means that you get the JDK from Oracle's site, Tomcat from Apache's site and so on. This also means that you are getting the originator's package format which is probably a tarball. Even in cases where the upstream provides a .deb you may not be able to use it if it specifies dependencies that you don't want to pull from Ubuntu, but want to control yourself. In the case of Oracle Java, I just tar zxvf the tarball, mv the resulting directory to /opt and add entries to /etc/bash.bashrc for JAVA_HOME and the PATH variable. Same thing with most Apache tools such as Tomcat. Ideally, don't wget (or curl) the packages from the external Internet site, but download them once and put them on an internal http server to deploy to your servers.

The other choice is to set up your own local repo in Debian format and add your mission critical packages to it. Then add this to your sources and configure the preference to be higher than the LTS repo so that your package overrides LTS. To do this you have to download the tarballs and build your own .deb packages, including defining dependencies so that your own dependency packages get pulled in. This is preferable for a large installation, say over 50 servers, but otherwise it isn't going to save much effort beyond a well written bash script.

Now, when a security update comes up, grab a copy of the new tarball, put it on your http server and change your bash script (or build your new .deb), then run the bash script remotely on all servers via ssh ( or use SaltStack or Ansible to help with this).

As far as always using the latest minor version, I would not recommend that. When a new version comes out you should always read the release notes, decide whether or not the changes are useful or necessary for you, run some internal tests on a test server, and only then upgrade. If the changes are small or will have minimal impact on you, it is OK to lag a few versions behind. The important thing is that you control the whole process, you make the decisions and weigh the pros and cons for YOUR situation, and then go ahead and upgrade on your schedule. Sometimes the threat will demand that you upgrade now, and sometimes not; read the release notes to understand whe

Don't forget, you are not running Ubuntu or Centos. You are running Linux. Ubuntu and Centos can make some tasks easier, especially when setting up a new server, but underneath it all, 99% or more of your system is stock standard Linux, and it is infinitely malleable.

Comment: I'd be careful with your last assertion. Especially in "professional server administration" environment. While you might get away with saying "Centos, oracle, and red hat are mostly the same", tacking on a "and debian or xyz linux" is a great way to complicate getting enterprise support. Many vendors will only offer support contracts with red hat binary compatible distros. I've also seen many servers administered the way you present... Often the well meaning sys admin installs all the latest bells and whistles and then the server falls into neglect. Custom compiles like this are a bal. act.

Comment: I just have single webapp  running on a single server & I think it might not be worth the hassle to maintain a repo/prepare .deb packages etc. While I don't have any specific feature requirements for Tomcat or JRE that force me to use a particular newer version. I was asking this just to ensure that if I'm running an older version supplied by ubuntu(installed from through `apt-get install`), am I safe in terms of security & quality of software? Do these software packages will be updated to a newer minor version later while I m sticking to a particular LTS version ?

Comment: Thanks you so much Dillion for posting such a detailed explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

Stay with what the Ubuntu supplies, assuming it still supplies security updates. If it is end of life then migrate to a newer install.

Update: I am unable to comment, so I rebut Mr. Dillon's answer. Software versions offered by Linux vendors, like Ubuntu, may be older, but they are well tested and proven reliable compared to fresh releases from the software developers. Having to build your own application stack, test it, and deploy it is expensive and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact what ever application vendors / developers responsible for the apps running in Tomcat. While the Ubuntu repository is likely the best bet... Vendors may ( and often do) have specific java version requirements.

And if you are the developer of all webapps on your tomcat instance, the responsibility of this choice rests in your hands.

Answer (score 0):

When reading through the answers, I think two crucial things are missing and important.

1. No open Linux Vendor does extensive checks on compatibility with Software like Tomcat, its too niche and varied. I think only Red Hat does this with JBoss for their entire stack, and only guarantees stuff when you use their enterprise support and version.
2. Most applications that run on Tomcat are custom made, otherwise they already provide their own internal application server as a recommendation (e.g. Jira, Confluence, Jenkins). And for most custom made applications the only answer is to test it.

To answer the question.

Typically sticking to the latest minor version makes sense, but within reason. So only upgrade when you see a bug that does affects you or is security related within your domain (if it fixes a security bug in e.g. Applets you don't have to upgrade). You can also do this directly out of the Linux distribution, for Oracle JDK and Tomcat there are PPA repositories that provide the latest versions outside of Ubuntu's update cycle.

Having said that, depending on what your application does, also minor upgrade can break things. Especially when you move into reflection and byte code generation you have to be careful (this also goes for libraries like Hibernate). We had stuff break when upgrading a minor version of Sun JDK because a library had problems with the new byte code.

But that what tests are for. So just make sure that your devs and build environments use the same version you will have on the server, otherwise you will break things sooner or later.